# Are there languages where grammatical parallelism does not matter?

Tags: syntax, english, grammar, list-of-languages

English has a strong preference for parallelism [(Wikipedia link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)), even though sentences lacking parallelism are still considered grammatically correct:

---

Good:

> She likes cooking, jogging, and reading.

Not as good:

> She likes cooking, jogging, and to read.

---

I wonder if there are languages without such a preference?

Comment: I don’t think this is primarily a linguistic thing. The human _brain_ likes recognisable patterns (they play a big role in how we interpret and experience the world, going all the way back to our proto-brains efficiently registering dangers in our environ), and parallelism is a neat way to generate recognisable and predictable patterns in language. I’d say it’s likely to be fairly universal.